Inspired by [the?] Hemingway's novel [...]

Inspired by [the?] Hemingway's novel For Whom the Bell Tolls, I read all his book.

As far as I know, normally the title should be preceded with a definite article:
I've a read the For Whom the Bell Tolls novel and I loved it.
But what about the first exmple? Do we need to put the there?

You must either say "I've read Hemingway's [novel] For Whom the Bell Tolls" (no article) OR "I've read the Hemingway [novel] For Whom the Bell Tolls" (no possessive). It's completely ungrammatical to include both. In either case, the noun novel is optional (less so in the second version), and wouldn't normally be included if you and your audience / readers were reasonably familiar with important books and writers within English Literature (they don't need to be reminded that it's a novel, obviously).

"I've a read" is not valid English.

You are wrong to always use an article with titles of novels.  You don't need the word "novel". In this case you should write

I've read For Whom the Bell Tolls,  and I loved it.

If you need the word "novel" then use an appositive "I've read the novel, For whom..."
A determiner, such as "Hemingway's" can go in place of "The",

Hemingway's novel, For whom...

or you can omit "novel" (if you think it is well known enough)

I've read Hemingway's For whom a bell tolls, and I loved it.

